# Using Like function in Access

Tags: ms-access, filter, sql-like

When using the Like function, is it simply adding a Not to the front of it to make it a Not Like function?

Answer (score 1):

And the long answer is `Yes` it will.

Answer (score 0):

The long answer is - it depends. If you are using `like` in a query, `not like` will work very well, however, it may not work if you are using it in a filter and will not work in a VBA comparison.